# strange issue with double.parse conversion

Tags: c#, textbox, double, currency

Im using visual studio 2010, windows form.

I have this code, that permit to convert money from USD to EUR. This is reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17909/Simple-Class-to-get-Currency-Exchange-Rates

This is code:

```
CurrencyConverter2 cc = new CurrencyConverter2();
cc.AdjustToLocalTime = true;

CurrencyData cd = new CurrencyData("USD", "EUR");
// Convert US Dollars to Euros

cc.GetCurrencyData(ref cd);

label5.Text = (5000 / cd.Rate).ToString();
```

OUTPUT IN THIS CASE IS : 3753,75375375375

But if I place value (example 5000) from texbox in this way:

```
double cambiamo = double.Parse(tbxDaConvertire.Text);
tbxConvertito.Text = (cambiamo * cd.Rate).ToString();
```

OUTPUT IS: 3752,5

I dont understand because Im getting this value!
How can I solve it please?

Comment: Are you sure that cd.Rate is the same? If you put a breakpoint in the code, check each of the values in turn to check that you aren't seeing rounding issues and that the inputs are the same. Note that your linked article mentions that it gets live rate data from Yahoo, so it is likely that the FX rate will have moved.

Comment: When working with currency values you should be using `decimal` instead of `double` because of precision.

Comment: Double Rate = 1.3320; Console.WriteLine(5000 / Rate); Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse("5000") / Rate); Are you sure you use the same Rate ?

Comment: Unlikely but possble: have the exchange rates changed between runs (cd.Rate changed - check values in same run using breakpoints)

Comment: the call cc.GetCurrencyData(ref cd); is likely gettng LIVE data (changng the exchange rate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first conversion used a conversion rate of 0.75075

Your second conversion used a conversion rate of 0.75050

Just a 0.00025 difference, easily found back in this chart of the conversion rate of the past week:

[image]

Note the extreme volatility, the rate changes in *minutes*.  Or to put it another way, it changed while you edited your code.  Clearly you are getting live updates from your currency conversion service.

Comment: thanks for this important info!

Answer (score 3):

As comments have pointed out:

```
        double cdRate = 1.42f;

        var value1 = (5000 / cdRate).ToString();
        var value2 = (double.Parse("5000") / cdRate).ToString();
        var value3 = (5000.0f / cdRate).ToString();

        //    value1 = "3521.12686697913"
        //    value2 = "3521.12686697913"            
        //    value3 = "3521.12686697913"
```

It is most likely that your CD rate is different. For a start in your first example you use `5000 / cd.Rate` and in your second you use `5000 * cd.Rate` - have you at some time performed `cd.Rate = 1/cd.Rate`? That could be where the discrepancy is arising.

Comment: Why are you using a `float` in there? `double` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Agreed - likely the `cc.GetCurrencyData(ref cd);` is calling a webservce with live data and the OP is using an old 'written' down variable result instead of examining the actual output or doing the math... +1

Comment: @Kendall I was trying to point out that the datatype of the first parameter should not affect the result in this case